# How to migrate api call wrapper from a redux thunk to redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I have recently started using redux-saga and I'm really liking it.

I have the following wrapper which I was using for my api calls which would take a promise (my api call), and display a preloader and handle errors.

```
export const callApi = (promise: Promise<any>, errorMsg: string = 'Api error') => (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setLoading(true));
  return promise.then(
    (response) => {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
      return response.body;
    },
    (error) => {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
      dispatch(apiError(errorMsg, error));
      return error;
    });
};
```

I'm unsure how I would replicate behaviour like this in redux saga. I couldnt find any example of doing anything like this?

---

So far I've come up with

```
const camelizeKeysPromise = (obj) => Promise.resolve(camelizeKeys(obj));


export function* sagaCallApi(promise: Promise<any>, errorMsg: string = 'Api error') {
   yield put(setLoading(true));
   try {
      const response = yield call(promise);
      try {
        const result = yield call(camelizeKeysPromise(response.body));
        return result;
      } catch (e) {
        return response.body;
      }
   } catch (exception) {
      yield put(setLoading(false));
      yield put(apiError(errorMsg, error));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yielding a `call` to promise will not return the desired response. You can use `eventChannel` from `redux-saga` to create a channel that emits the response on success or the error object on failure and then subscribe to the channel in your saga.

```
const promiseEmitter = promise => {
  return eventChannel(emit => {
    promise.then(
      response => emit({response}),
      error => emit({error})
    );
  });
};
```

Modify your new saga by replacing the call to the promise with this:

```
const channel = yield call(promiseEmitter, promise);
const {response, error} = yield take(channel);
if(response){
  // handle success
  return response;
}else if(error){
  // handle failure
  yield put(setLoading(false));
  yield put(apiError(errorMsg, error));
}
```

Be aware that there might be syntactical errors in my code as I wrote this without an editor, but you can get the general approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just been reading up on channels. Am I right in thinking this wouldn't be needed if instead of a promise, i passed a function returning a promise?

Comment: You'll probably end up with the same problem since you will get promise and not the the response if you yield a call effect to that function, unless I missinderstood your question.